# When I edit a file with EMACS I get a strange error. How do I fix this?

Tags: command-line, emacs, command-line-interface

This is what I am doing:

1. Make a file or use an existing file.
2. Emacs filename.txt.
3. Type some new text into the file.
4. Save file.

After step 2, I receive an error after the emacs editor window pops up.

Here is the error:

> 2022-01-19 22:11:53.935 Emacs-x86_64-10_14[33893:994906] It's not
> legal to call -layoutSubtreeIfNeeded on a view which is already being
> laid out.  If you are implementing the view's -layout method, you can
> call -[super layout] instead. Break on void
> _NSDetectedLayoutRecursion(void) to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future.

I have already tried updating emacs and that didn't help, and googling didn't give me an answer. Currently, I have GNU Emacs 27.1 version.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question here or elsewhere?  I specifically remember commenting.  What happened to that question, please?

Comment: If I run the Emacs binary directly (eg. ./Emacs-27.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs) then I see the same error when Emacs starts, both in Emacs 27 and in pretest-28.0.90.  However, if you just run Emacs normally (as in start it from Finder or the Dock) then you won't see the error, and it shouldn't impact your usage of Emacs at all.  Apart from the message, is it causing you any problem at all?

Comment: @stevoooo: Please consider posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you shouldn't need to "fix" the error at all and it won't cause any problems while you're actually running Emacs.  In fact I'm somewhat surprised you see it at all.

I was only able to see the error (in both Emacs 27 and in pretest-28.0.90) only by running the Emacs binary (eg. ./Emacs-27.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs) directly from a terminal, which isn't the normal way of starting Emacs on macOS.  If you just run Emacs by starting it from Finder, the Dock, or via the "open" utility then you shouldn't see the error at all, and it shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: How would I edit a file by running it through Finder instead of using the command line interface?

Comment: You can drag and drop the file onto the Emacs icon or into the Emacs window if it's running already, or use one of the many ways in Emacs for "finding" (its term for loading a file for editing) files.  If you're not sure of those then the Emacs tutorial (available from the menubar) is a great place to get started.

Comment: I'm getting this error on the terminal in a completely different app having nothing whatsoever to do with emacs.  It seems to occur completely repeatedly the first time I hit Cmd-T to bring up the system's floating window font picker.  Running on MacOS 12.1 on an M1 MacBook Pro laptop under Xcode 13.3.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of keyboard interaction (and emacs in particular) is that there's no need to touch the mouse. It's possible to log in (using e.g. ssh) and edit remotely, with no gui (so no way to drag and drop), and this is the 'normal' way of invoking emacs. Run 'emacs --help' from the command line to see a bunch of options. In particular see 'emacs --no-window-system' which uses a raw terminal even when a gui is available (no error message appears when it's run this way).

The gui however adds font and image support, which can be useful if you're sitting at the machine. The error message you get when you invoke 'emacs' from the command line in its default mode, with no arguments, is a diagnostic describing a bug in the mac gui implementation.

The error's still there if you start emacs through the finder; you can see that by running (e.g.)

```
$ open /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-x86_64-10_14
```

which both opens an emacs gui and a terminal window containing the program's text output.

As it says in the message, 'this may break in the future'; it's not helpful to say 'you're using it wrong.'

Comment: Apparently this is fixed in emacs 28 --  http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=53481

Comment: Thank you for the insight! Since I am not actually using it wrong, how do I stop getting the error message and prevent future 'breakage'?

Comment: Thanks so much Roger!

Comment: It isn't.  The version of 28.1 being distributed from emacsformacos.com still emits the warning.  Just FYI.

Comment: 28.2 still emits the message.

Comment: I just updated to Emacs 29.1 and I am getting this error.

Comment: I am getting this error with Emacs 30.0.50.